# How to correctly convert Year-month to Year-quarter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert a `pandas dataframe` containing date in `YYYYMM` format to `YYYYQ` format as below

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['200612']})
pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(dat.date), freq='Q')
```

However this generates output as `2012Q2`, whereas correct output should be `2006Q4`

What is the right way to get correct Quarter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specific the input format:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['200612']})
pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(dat.date, format='%Y%m'), freq='Q')
```

Output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2006Q4'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', name='date')
```